# Rails initialization

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am looking at the Rails 5 initialization process and in the file 'ruby_executable_hooks' we have the following line:

```
require 'executable-hooks/hooks'
```

where does ruby load the 'hooks.rb' file from? I can't find it in the $LOAD_PATH. Also what functionality does executable-hooks add to the initialization process in rails 5?

Answer (score 1):

executable-hooks is gem that hook into rubygems executables allowing extra actions to be taken before executable is run.

Probably this code from rvm if you use it.

Source code:
https://github.com/rvm/executable-hooks